# How to go about containing scrollable views within a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I wrote a FragmentActivity app with the use of the v4 support library, consisting of a fragment with a layout that contains a listview (list fragment), and a reusable fragment that changes its layout based on the list item selected (detail fragment).

In the layout for large screens, I have a fragment tag for the list fragment and a scrollview as a fragment container for the detail fragment, to allow fragments whose layouts overflow out of the screen.

Originally, for small screens, I used a basic ScrollView as the fragment container. But, since the listview in the list fragment is a scrollable fragment and there cannot be scrollable views in a ScrollView, it couldn't be scrolled; though the other fragments could be scrolled.

So, I changed the ScrollView to a FrameLayout instead, and while fragments with scrollable views can scroll, the fragments that overflowed the screen could not be scrolled.

How would I go about this problem, with the intention of enabling both fragments with scrollable views and overflowing fragments to scroll in a one-panel fragment view?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I might be able to use ScrollView in the dynamic layouts used by the detail fragment as I see fit, using it where there are no scrollable views, but are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess this does require the ScrollView to be used only in layouts in which there are no  scrollable views.

I stopped using ScrollView as the root element in the fragment activity layout, and I manually used ScrollViews where applicable, and it's working now.

A better way is still welcome and appreciated.